# Auto position an image on top of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a map of 2D data that I created, but would like to add a logo to the map as well. I want the image to auto position itself based on the size of the figure that I created. I can do that manually like this:

```
im = Image.open('E:/Riskpulse_HD/Cefetra/Riskpulse_logo.png')
fig.set_dpi(150)
plt.figimage(im, xo=1000, yo=135)
```

However, if the figure changes sizes due to long title, colorbar size, etc., the logo will be in the wrong position. How can I automate the position so it always fits nicely in the bottom right hand corner? For reference, all figure sizes I create are size (10,12).

Example figure:

[image]

Comment: probably you will have to calculate it manually. `im.size` gives you `(width, height)` for image and you will need `height, width` for map/plot and then `xo = map_width - im_width`

Answer (score 0):

You can get image size

```
im_width, im_height = im.size

print(im_width, im_height)
```

and plot size

```
bbox = plt.gca().get_window_extent()

print(bbox.x0, bbox.y0, bbox.x1, bbox.y1)
```

and calculate position in bottom right corner

```
plt.figimage(im, xo=bbox.x1-im_width, yo=bbox.y0)
```

Eventually you may need some margins

```
margin_x = 20
margin_y = 20

plt.figimage(im, xo=bbox.x1-im_width-margin_x, yo=bbox.y0+margin_y)
```

---

**EDIT:** I added function which moves image to corner when window is resized.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# --- functions ---

def on_resize(event):
    #print(event)

    bbox = plt.gca().get_window_extent()
    print(bbox.x0, bbox.y0, bbox.x1, bbox.y1)

    logo.ox = bbox.x1-im_width-margin_x
    logo.oy = bbox.y0+margin_y

# --- main ---

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])

im = Image.open('square-1.png')
im_width, im_height = im.size
print(im_width, im_height)

bbox = plt.gca().get_window_extent()
print(bbox.x0, bbox.y0, bbox.x1, bbox.y1)

margin_x = 20
margin_y = 20
logo = plt.figimage(im, xo=bbox.x1-im_width-margin_x, yo=bbox.y0+margin_y)

# connect function which will move image when window is resized
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', on_resize)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I added function which moves image to corner when window is resized.